# garage walls wet

Tags: walls, leak, garage, moisture, wet

[image: one side of wall]HI, I am purchasing a home and noticed some spots in the garage walls? Not sure if its moisture or a leak since its on the same place on both sides. Any advise will be greatly appreciated.

[image: other wall]

Comment: you need to ask a question.

Comment: Could just be staining from before the foundation was backfilled or any number of other reasons. Have you actually detected moisture?

Comment: what is outside the walls.   You need more pictures.  Also guessing the house may extend above the garage?

Answer (score 1):

Moisture on below grade walls is common. The lucky thing for you there is not much depth there IF it becomes a problem.

Normally we put foundation drains in to drain the water away. This may not have been done since it’s not very deep.

If it becomes a problem it is fairly easy to put drains in or you may be able to have it done as part of the purchase.